# NelmioApiDocBundle can´t parser mongoDB Document

Tags: mongodb, symfony, doctrine, nelmioapidocbundle

I use NelmioApiDocBundle for documentation of my API-Rest. If I use entity class, documentation (Input and Output) is created correctly. Nevertheless, Nelmio isn´t creating documentation for Document class of MongoDB :(

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you've reviewed the latest version of Nelmio?  [link]https://github.com/nelmio/NelmioApiDocBundle

Comment: Yes, But I find nothing.